# Can I make Eclipse UI use bigger text (other than the editor window)

Tags: eclipse, user-interface

In Eclipse, I know that I can make the program source text have any font I have. My problem is with the rest of the UI text which for my eyes is too tiny. Is there a setting for changing that?

Answer (score 0):

in the eclipse installations plugins folder find **org.eclipse.ui.themes_/css/e4_basestyle.css**

and add following lines to the end of the file (adjust to your prefered font size)

```
* {
  font-size:14;
}
```

Hope this helps!